# How to auto update an acf field based on the condition?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have two custom post types with acf fields.
Custom Post_A, which has 2 fields - title / submitted
Custom Post_B, which has 2 fields - title / percent
Both Post_A and B have the same title (which is the logged in user's name) and they already exist.

When a field ‘submitted’ has the value ‘done’ in Post_A, I need to automatically update a ‘percent’ field with a value ‘50’ in Post_B. 
I tried the following code but it doesn't update ‘50’ to Post_B.
Would you please correct my code?

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'author'            => get_current_user_id(),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post_a',
    'meta_key'          => 'submitted',
    'meta_value'        => 'done'
));

$the_query = new WP_Query( $posts );
$the_count = count($the_query); 

if($the_count>0) {
foreach ($the_query as $is_done){
$my_post = array();
$my_post['post_type'] = 'post_b';
$my_post['post_title'] = the_title();

// Update the post into the database
$field_key = "field_606cb546456343";
$value = "50";
update_field( $field_key, $value);
}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `save_post_{$post->post_type}` action hook that will trigger on specific post type. check the below code.

```
function update_post_b( $post_id, $post, $update ){

    $post_a_title = get_the_title( $post_id );

    $posts = array(
        'author'            => get_current_user_id(),
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'post_b'
    );

    $post_b = new WP_Query( $posts );

    if( $post_b->have_posts() ){ while ( $post_b->have_posts() ) { $post_b->the_post();
        if( $post_a_title == get_the_title() ){
            update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'percent', 50 );    
        }
    } }

}
add_action( 'save_post_post_a', 'update_post_b', 10, 3 );
```

**USEFUL LINKS**

- [save_post_{$post->post_type}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/)

Comment: Hi Bhautik: Thank you for your help. Can I ask a question? There are many posts that the current user has posted. I only  need to update a post_b that has the same title with post_a. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Hi Bhautik:  Well, actually this is the same questions of this topic... I see, I'll ask it agin. Thanks anyway : )

Comment: Thank again for your supportive help. Wow, it works, have a nice weekend  : )

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.